# Embedding native android component within a cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

Is it possible to embed a native Android component within a Cordova application?

Interacting with a component is possible (using `cordova.exec()`),
however I am not sure how to instantiate & place a component on the screen in the first place.

---

Details:

To be clear, I am not asking about creating an app where the "outer" app is native, and an "inner" part of the app is a webview controlled by Cordova. I am asking about an app, which is entirely a webview controlled by Cordova, and putting native components within that webview.

The component I am trying to place within my app is  [a handwriting recognition component](http://doc.myscript.com/MyScriptATK/Android/sltw/index.html). In a pure native Android app, one would place it within the app using `res/layout`:

```
<com.myscript.atk.sltw.SingleLineTextWidgetStyleable
  android:id="@+id/sltw"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

... and I am looking to achieve similar,
using Javascript within a Cordova application.

Comment: you can create plugins that show native elements, do a search on github, admob plugins show native ads, and some other plugins show date pickers or other native elements

Comment: ah, I did google before asking (of course!), however, I only came across examples of native apps containing webview, but none the other way around. care to link to a specific example @jcesarmobile ?

Comment: @jcesarmobile [This one](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker/blob/master/plugin.xml) looks like it could be a good example to follow - thanks! Let me know if you'd recommend using a different one as a reference.

Comment: there are a few admob plugins that display the ad view over the webview, and the google maps plugin shows a native map